# Software for large polynomials

Tags: polynomials, math-software

I have 6th degree polynomial with lots of terms for each degree. I've been trying to expand it and solve it by hand - but it has gotten to the point where it takes at least 1 full page of paper to write out the equation. Is there any software out there that can help you expand polynomials and group like terms that can handle large equations like this?

I've tried Wolfram|Alpha -but it doesn't appear to be able to handle equations this large.

Comment: Try Sage.  You can use it for free at cocalc.com

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks :)

Comment: Sympy for Python can handle large polynomials easily (and is free as opposed to most options). I have been able to generate characteristic polynomials for graphs of degree 30 with my specs before it stopped bothering to simplify.

Comment: Yes, try sage, www.sagemath.org. The language is using Python as base languange and collects "all" free (and not free) computer algebra systems i know, the "batteries", in one framework that can thus switch between structure in an easy, supporting way. This machine commenting is a linux box with one  terminal running sage as long as it is on power.

Comment: (4 years later) I have similar problem, did you find a solution?